# Is it possible to access Principal in UserDetailsService?

Tags: spring-security

I have implemented a custom `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` which returns a `Principal` (actually an `Object` as per the signature) in the method `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest)`.

I am custom-implementing a `UserDetailsService` which needs to access the `Principal` somehow. I have tried using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`, which is throwing a `NullPointerException` since `getAuthentication()` is null.

How do I access the `Principal` otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is null is that spring security was not able to identify the principal up to that point. Extract from the javadoc of [AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html):

> Base class for processing filters that handle pre-authenticated
>   authentication requests, where it is assumed that the principal has
>   already been authenticated by an external system.

UserDetailService is responsible for loading the user object. Then, after successful authentication, principal will be set containing the given user object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`, I implemented `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.AuthenticationUserDetailsService<Authentication>`, which was the actual necessity for `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`. The `loadUserDetails()` method in this gets the `Authentication` object as a parameter and hence my issue is resolved.